# Status: 400; Message: Token validated, but invalid for app <app_id>

Tags: python, django, pusher

I'm building an application with Python (Django) and trying to trigger an event to be received by another application, brokered by Pusher.

When trying to trigger the event I am getting the following error:

Status: 400; Message: Token validated, but invalid for app <app_id>

The code I am using for testing the connection and event trigger is the following:

```
import pusher
p = pusher.Pusher(app_id=settings.PUSHER_APP_ID, key=settings.PUSHER_API_KEY, secret=settings.PUSHER_SECRET)
p['a_channel'].trigger('an_event', {'some': 'data'})
```

I already verified that all the credential parameters I pass to the Pusher constructor are correct and even used them directly in the call, but no joy.

This happens both in the Django application and in a command line script, both with the exact same result.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: That message isn't very helpful, is it! It sounds like the authentication process validated (the request was properly signed) but that that somehow it didn't match up with the the `app_id`. I think the Web API response is cryptic enough that it's worth pinging Pusher support about.

Comment: Hey Phil! Thanks for replying. I have already sent them a message but was hoping it would be something daft from my part that another set of eyes could easily spot, or something common enough that someone else knew how to solve. I guess I'll wait to see what Pusher's support. Cheers!

Comment: The only thing that sprung to mind was to double, treble, quadruple-check that the credentials you are setting are correct. I know you said you'd verified the credential parameters. But, *any* chance the app_id, app_key and app_secret have been mixed up e.g. using the app_key where the app_id is required. The response suggests a credentials mix-up.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem and the solution was as @leggetter suggested and I had the env app_id and app_secret incorrectly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate for others. I found this question when my circleci build wasn't working with the same values.

If you are using a config.yml file, the app_id is treated as an integer. For some reason this confuses the pusher authentication mechanism. You have to wrap your id in quotes, for example:

```
docker:
  image: ...
  environment:
    PUSHER_APP_ID: "12345"
```

As opposed to the *incorrect* version:

```
docker:
  image: ...
  environment:
    PUSHER_APP_ID: 12345
```

The other values do not suffer from this, as they contain letters which forces the YAML parser to treat the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks, Abe. This is actually a type of problem I have encountered multiple times with other pieces of software since posting this question. Never thought of coming here to update it, though, so thanks for doing that. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had exactly the same error and you helped me out quickly :-)